# playing python game background-music without delaying the actual game

Tags: python, os.system, background-music

I am making a hangman python game to get to know the python syntax but as the code plays the background music .wav file, the code delays until the end of the music instead of running simultaneously.

I have tried using the os.system command (from the os library) and also subprocess.popen() in order to open the music in a new script window using a different script file but nothing worked.

```
import os
def music(): #this is the in-game function that is supposed to run the music
    os.system("musicforhangmaninit.py")


import winsound #this is the command that plays the .wav file music created earlier by this script

winsound.PlaySound('hangmanadditionals.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

no error messages appeared but I think that I got the os.system() function wrong because it seems to do nothing at all, the subprocess.popen() played the music but still delayed the game. (the goal output was the music playing simultaneously with the game I made)

P.s. : I prefer a solution that works on all the operating systems or at least Linux and windows

Comment: The example above code will definitely delay (as is). Have you tried the SND_ASYNC parameter?

Comment: would you care to write an example of what it would look like?